# wso2 puppet address 169.254.169.254 is not avaiable

Tags: wso2

We are tryng to install wso2 puppet agent as described in [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Creating+a+Cartridge+on+OpenStack). In the "Step 2 - Configuring the cartridge", we got an error because the site address `169.254.169.254` is not available. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

An 169.254.x.x address is generally also known in a Microsoft environment as APIPA (Automatically Provided IP Address). This kind of address is provided when your host requests a dynamic IP-address through DHCP, but there is no DHCP server present, or can not be reached.

More info on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address